# Critique of short essay

Tags: essay, description, goal, flow

Basically I need some critics regarding the following points:

1. Does this description essay archive its goal (a creepy story with a 'sappy' ending)?
2. How is the 'rhythm' of the story (is there sometimes too sudden or too long?).

> Pets make you feel safe, useful, and
> needed. Mine was an exception (at
> least that's what I thought.) She was
> a shy little kitten named Luz. My mom
> gave her to me for my fourteenth
> birthday. She was the cutest baby cat
> I had ever seen. Her fur was smooth
> and dark gray, and it always used to
> reflect the sun and shine. But when
> she started getting older, her fur
> became very thick. It was getting
> darker and darker until one day, it
> became totally black. I really started
> to hate her. Even thought she was like
> a black curse, as time passed, she
> turned out to be the shiniest spark I
> ever had in my life.
>
> She never made
> a single noise when she was walking in
> my old house. She just suddenly
> appeared everywhere I was. She become
> almost like a creepy version of my
> shadow. She was always so silent even
> when she was hungry. The only moment I
> used to hear noises from her was at
> night. She was like a baby ghost
> crying her sadness through the hall.
> Her sound was a mixture of sadness,
> anguish and frustration. Her cries
> were always in my mind, drilling in my
> thoughts, detaching me from
> consciousness, and driving me slowly
> into a strange state of melancholy and
> panic. The night was never silent the
> time she was around.
>
> After she stopped crying, she used to come to my bedroom to stay in the
> darkest place of the room; The exact
> place where moonlight never touched.
> Then, she started to stare at me with
> her big, yellow and hellish eyes. Her
> stare was so creepy that sometimes I
> felt like she could see the deepest
> fears that were hidden in my mind. She
> could pass through my eyes and immerse
> herself directly into my thoughts. Her
> evil eyes were always haunting me in
> nightmares.
>
> Her eyes weren't the
> only creepy part of her body. Every
> time I petted her, I felt like I was
> touching the corpse of a dead
> creature. Her body was just bones and
> tissues. Her skin was the same color
> of raw meat. It was so colorless, with
> no sign of life. It was so cold that
> sometimes it really made me wonder if
> that thing was really alive.   The
> only thing that made me feel that she
> was alive was her smell. But it wasn't
> pleasant, because it was like the
> smell of a animal in decomposition. It
> was like blood, cat food and fish put
> together. At the beginning I really
> couldn't stand it, but as time passed,
> I got used to that smell. It was
> weird, but it filled the room with the
> sensation that someone was there.
>
> The time passed and the black and
> creepy Luz was getting old, until one
> day she died. In the beginning, I was
> so happy because the curse of my days
> was finally gone. But later on, I
> started to have sleeping problems. The
> nights became so empty. No one was
> following me, watching my steps,
> watching my sleep and my dreams
> anymore. Luz was gone forever, and for
> the first time in my life, I was alone
> in the dark.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vote to close for not following directions for posting critiques. http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/181/policy-change-writing-critique-questions-now-welcome

Comment: I agree with Ralph.  This needs to be edited to tell us *what* you are looking for.  We are not a group of free editors or beta readers.  Your other critique questions (which this should be tagged as) have provided us with guidelines for what you wanted to do with your work.

Comment: OK I edited the question. Is it OK now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your writing style is stream-of-consciousness, which can be hard to digest. (On the internet this is labeled "tl;dr" for "too long; didn't read.") I *strongly* suggest breaking this into several paragraphs.

Second, you start out with how despite your objection to her color, she became an emotional bright spot — but you don't get to that until the end, and then you quickly hurry past it. You spend most of the essay dwelling on the "before" part of your feelings.

You should structure it roughly:

- Intro: pets are great. mine wasn't,
  until she was. Cute baby cat to all-black
  cat whom I hated, and then loved.
- Para 1: Silent by day, loud
  distressing cries at night
- Para 2: How she felt and smelled
- **Para 3: How my feelings changed and
  why [this is the part you're missing]**
- Conclusion: Luz is gone and I miss her

Comment: Yeah I felt I was missing Para 3 before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just some remarks:

Were you *really* touching any corpse, anytime? Because this metaphor smells foul.

"Alone in the dark". I think it is a cliche. It is the name of well known legend among computer games, so this phrase induces feelings of a dangerous situation, not loneliness, loss and deprivation.

Comment: I disagree; "alone in the dark" evokes loneliness and sadness in those of us *not* steeped in computer games. In the Ray Charles biopic *Ray,* Jamie Foxx is complaining to another character about his blindness: "When I walk out that door, I walk out alone the dark." He was referring to his entire life. http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ray_%28film%29